# VSCode syntax matching constants in string

Tags: regex, visual-studio-code

I am having an issue in that VSCode syntax highlighting is recognizing numeric values within strings.   I was under the impression that when a begin/end capture occurs, that everything within it was treated as a string and subsequent rules would not execute.

In my syntax file I have the following definitions:

```
    {
        "name": "string.quoted.single.proc",
        "begin": "'",
        "beginCaptures": { "0": { "name": "punctuation.definition.quotes.begin.single.proc" } },
        "end": "'",
        "endCaptures": { "0": { "name": "punctuation.definition.quotes.end.single.proc" } },
        "patterns": [{
            "include": "$self"
        }]
    },

    {
        "name": "constant.numeric.floating-point.proc", 
        "match": "(\\.\\d+([Ee][-+]\\d+)?i?)\\b|\\b\\d+\\.\\d*(([Ee][-+]\\d+)?i?\\b)?"
    },

    {
        "name": "constant.numeric.integer.proc", 
        "match": "\\b((0x[0-9a-fA-F]+)|(0[0-7]+i?)|(\\d+([Ee]\\d+)?i?)|(\\d+[Ee][-+]\\d+i?))\\b"
    },
```

However, when I have text such as:

```
Parse( $year & '-01-01', 'yyyy-MM-dd' );
```

The two "01" values are highlighted as if they were a numeric literal.

In the numeric constant match expressions, do I have to explicitly filter out if the number is within quotes?

Answer (score 0):

I think I just realized my issue.  The problem was due to

```
"patterns": [{
    "include": "$self"
}]
```

Once I removed the internal pattern matching (i.e. for escape sequence matching), it worked.   However, I guess I don't understand how the patterns is working in this case with regard to the numeric literals rule.